# How to use MessageQueue feature of appserver.io inside existing laravel project

Tags: php, multithreading, laravel, appserver

My existing Laravel project is such that all the tasks are executed sequentially. I have identified part of the code which can be run in parallel using `PHP` threads and can reduce the response time.

Instead of using [`pthreads`](https://github.com/krakjoe/pthreads/tree/PHP5), there was suggestion given that why not use appserver.io - which is fully multithreaded `php` server itself. One can use its `MessageQueue` feature, add all your job to this queue, and it will automatically fork worker threads. You don't have to manage anything.

I have already deployed existing Laravel app on appserver.io (copied project under `/opt/appserver/webapps/` folder) but now I don't know how to use appserver's `MessageQueue`. My project uses `psr-4`, where as appserver is `psr-0`. Laravel has it's own DI and so does appserver.

All I want to do is, use appserver's `MessageQueue` to get more workers executing one function in parallel. I'm new to appserver and not sure how the directory structure should look like or what configuration I have do it. Any pointers will be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can connect and send to the `MessageQueue` from within your Laravel application. First you've to install the client library `appserver-io/messaging` by adding `"appserver-io/messaging" : "~1.0`" to your composer.json. Then you can send a message with

```
$queue = MessageQueue::createQueue('pms/myQueue');
$connection = QueueConnectionFactory::createQueueConnection('my-laravel-app');
$session = $connection->createQueueSession();
$sender = $session->createSender($queue);
$sender->send(new StringMessage('Some String'));
```

assuming you've an application named `my-laravel-app`, that resides in the folder `/opt/appserver/webapps/my-laravel-app` and a `MessageQueue` called `pms/myQueue`, defined in a file `META-INF/message-queues.xml`. The file would look like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<message-queues xmlns="http://www.appserver.io/appserver">
    <message-queue type="MyReceiverClass">
        <destination>pms/myQueue</destination>
    </message-queue>
</message-queues>
```

In that example, the receiver class `MyReceiverClass` has to be available under `/opt/appserver/webapps/my-laravel-app/META-INF/classes/MyLaravelApp/Receivers/MyReceiverClass` for example.

A good start is the [example](https://github.com/appserver-io-apps/example) application that comes with simple `MessageQueue` example running some simple import functionality.